# Object references pointing to the same object

Tags: java, class, pointers, reference

Let's say for instance that we have a class `Board` with many fields (i.e. a rather complex class).  We instantiate a Board like so:

```
Board b = new Board();
```

Note that for the sake of this example, I am not entering any parameters into the constructor, though in a real example, those may be necessary.  If we were to then instantiate a new instance of Board and set it equal to be like so:

```
Board c = b;
```

This would not actually create a new board.  From what I know, `c` and `b` now point to the same area of memory, the same Board object.  So, if I were to change something about `b`, say be incrementing an integer field, like so:

```
b.count++;//Assume count is an integer field in the Board class.
```

The value `c.count` should be incremented as well.  However, when I do this myself, it doesn't work.  `b.count` is incremented, yet `c.count` is not.  
Can anyone explain to me why this happens? This effect is something I want to have happen, thus any advice on how to implement this would be very helpful (General examples are fine).

Comment: Could you please post the example reproducing it

Comment: I'd _really_ like to see the example.

Comment: How every answer have the same example... I am starting to wonder if I can't see the code in the OP question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong again:

```
package cruft;

/**
 * Board description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 11/26/12 6:46 PM
 */
public class Board {

    public int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board();
        Board c = b;
        System.out.println("b before: " + b);
        System.out.println("c before: " + c);

        ++b.count;

        System.out.println("b after : " + b);
        System.out.println("c after : " + c);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Board");
        sb.append("{count=").append(count);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: To get technical, it should be `b.count++;`

Comment: So why don't you explain how ++i and i++ are different?  And how that is germane to the question?

Comment: In one the ++ is before the variable, in the other it's after. I think you know that. All I meant is it would be a better example if the code exactly matched the OP. I don't think it is germane, I think it's a technicality, as I said. I wasn't insulting you: I fully acknowledge how wonderful and infallible you are.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen. Take a look at this example.

```
public class Board {

    public Integer count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Board b = new Board();
        Board c = b;

        c.count++;

        System.out.println("b.count="+b.count);
        System.out.println("c.count="+c.count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen in a single thread.
if you do that c= b for a second thread, normal visibility rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to avoid using `public` fields in your objects. Use a `private` field, then use a `getFieldName()` and a `setFieldName(FieldType arg)` method. That way you have more control over what happens, and you can add code if you want other things to happen when a certain variable changes.

That being said, you must have a bug in your code, because:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board b = new Board();
    Board c = b;

    System.out.println("BEFORE++: b.count = " + b.count);
    System.out.println("BEFORE++: c.count = " + c.count);

    b.count++;

    System.out.println("AFTER++: b.count = " + b.count);
    System.out.println("AFTER++: c.count = " + c.count);
}

public static class Board {
    public int count = 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
BEFORE++: b.count = 0
BEFORE++: c.count = 0
AFTER++: b.count = 1
AFTER++: c.count = 1
```